Mendelson Introduction to Topology Lemma $6.4:$ $Y$ a subspace of $X$ in metric space setting implies $Y$ a subset of $X$ in topological space setting

Definition $6.1\ $ Let $(X,\mathfrak{I})$ and $(Y,\mathfrak{I}')$ be
topological spaces. The topological space $Y$ is called a subspace
of the topological space $X$ if $Y\subset X$ and if the open subsets
of $Y$ are precisely the subsets $O'$ of the form
$$ O' = O\cap Y$$
for some open subset $O$ of $X.$


My understanding of the second part of this definition is: $O'\in\mathfrak{I}'\implies \exists\ O\in\mathfrak{I}$ such that $O' = O\cap Y.$  Or equivalently (I think), $O\in\mathfrak{I}\implies O':=O\cap Y\in \mathfrak{I}'.$ Please confirm my understanding here is correct. Then comes:


Proposition $6.2\ $ Let $(X,\mathfrak{I})$ be a topological space and
let $Y$ be a subset of $X.$ Define the collection $\mathfrak{I}'$ of
subsets of $Y$ as the collection of subsets of $O'$ of $Y$ of the form
$$ O' = O\cap Y,$$
where $O\in \mathfrak{I}.$ Then $(Y,\mathfrak{I}')$ is a topological
space and therefore a subspace of $(X,\mathfrak{I})$ provided
$Y\neq\emptyset.$

I'm fine with the proof for this, so let's treat this as a theorem we can use.


Lemma $6.4\ $ Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $(Y,d')$ be a
subspace of $(X,d).$ If $(X,\mathfrak{I})$ is the topological space
associated with $(X,d)$ and $(Y,\mathfrak{I}')$ is the topological
space associated with $(Y,d),$ then $(Y,\mathfrak{I}')$ is a subspace
of $(X,\mathfrak{I}).$

Mendelson's proof:

Since $d'$ is the restriction of $d,$ an open ball in $(Y,d')$ is the
restriction of an open ball in $(X,d)$ to $Y.$ Consequently a subset
$O'$ of $Y$ is open in $Y$ if and only if, for each $y\in O',$ there
is an $\varepsilon_y>0$ such that $B(y;\varepsilon_y)\cap Y\subset
 O'.$ Let $O:= \displaystyle\bigcup_{y\in O'} B(y;\varepsilon_y).$ Then
$O$ is open in $X$ and $O'=O\cap Y.$ Thus $O'\in\mathfrak{I}'.$
Conversely, if $O'\in\mathfrak{I}',$ then $O'=O\cap Y$ for some
$O\in\mathfrak{I}.$ For each $y\in O'$ we have $y\in O,$ and $O$ is
open, so there is an $\varepsilon_y$ such that
$B(y;\varepsilon_y)\subset O.$ It follows that $B(y;\varepsilon_y)\cap
 Y\subset O',$ and hence $O'$ is open in $(Y,d').$


My understanding of Mendelson's proof is that it has the following structure:
If $O'$ is open in $Y,$ then there exists an open set $O$ of $X$ such that $O'=O\cap Y.$ Thus $O'\in \mathfrak{I}'.$ Conversely, if $O'\in\mathfrak{I}',$ then $O'$ is open in $(Y,d').$

Let's look at the first part of this:

If $O'$ is open in $Y,$ then there exists an open set $O$ of $X$ such
that $O'=O\cap Y.$ Thus $O'\in \mathfrak{I}'.$

I already don't get this, because surely if $O'$ is open in $Y,$ then we can immediately say "therefore $O'\in \mathfrak{I}'$", without any need for any in-between argument, because $(Y,\mathfrak{I}')=$ is the topological space associated with the metric space $(Y,d').$
Anyway, he needs to show either $O'\in\mathfrak{I}'\implies \exists\ O\in\mathfrak{I}$ such that $O' = O\cap Y.$  Or equivalently (I think), $O\in\mathfrak{I}\implies O':=O\cap Y\in \mathfrak{I}'.$ And I don't think he has shown either of these things, so I am a bit lost.
His proof needs to be of the form, "Suppose $O'\in\mathfrak{I}'.$ Then something something something, therefore $\exists\ O\in \mathfrak{I}$ such that $ O' = O\cap Y.$" So when he writes,

Conversely, if $O'\in\mathfrak{I}',$ then $O'=O\cap Y$ for some
$O\in\mathfrak{I}.$

his proof should end there, although obviously he has provided no justification for this statement. My suspicion is that Mendelson has proved the following, different theorem:
"Lemma $6.4a\ $" Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $(Y,d')$ be a subspace of $(X,d).$ If $(X,\mathfrak{I})$ is the topological space associated with $(X,d),$ and $(Y,\mathfrak{I}')$ is the subspace of $(X,\mathfrak{I})$ induced by $\mathfrak{I},$ then $(Y,\mathfrak{I}')$ is the associated topological space of the metric space $(Y,d').$
Do you agree with my suspicion?

Moving on, let me try to prove Mendelson's Lemma $6.4$ (which I think he did not do properly).
We must prove that $(Y,\mathfrak{I}')$ is a subspace of $(X,\mathfrak{I}).$ To do this, we can either show that $O'\in\mathfrak{I}'\implies \exists\ O\in\mathfrak{I}$ such that $O' = O\cap Y.$  Or equivalently (I think), $O\in\mathfrak{I}\implies O':=O\cap Y\in \mathfrak{I}'.$ I opt for the first approach. Let $O'\in\mathfrak{I}'.$ Then $O'$ is open in the metric space $(Y,d'),$ so for each $y\in O',$ there is an $\varepsilon_y>0$ such that $B_X(y,\varepsilon_y)\cap Y\subset O'.$ Let $O:=\displaystyle\bigcup_{y\in O'} B_X(y,\varepsilon_y).$ Then $O$ is open in $(X,d)$ and so $X\in\mathfrak{I},$ and $O'=O\cap Y.$ Therefore $(Y,\mathfrak{I})$ is a subspace of $(X,\mathfrak{I}).$
So is my understanding of all this correct? And if so, what did Mendelson intend here? Lemma $6.4$ with my proof, or "Lemma $6.4a$" with his proof?

$O'\in\mathfrak{I}'\implies \exists\ O\in\mathfrak{I}$ such that $O' = O\cap Y$ is not equivalent to $O\in\mathfrak{I}\implies O\cap Y\in \mathfrak{I}'.$ Definition 6.1 means the conjunction of these two properties, namely $O'\in\mathfrak{I}'\iff \exists\ O\in\mathfrak{I}$ such that $O' = O\cap Y$.


My understanding of the second part of this definition is: $O'\in\mathfrak{I}'\implies \exists\ O\in\mathfrak{I}$ such that $O' = O\cap Y.$  Or equivalently (I think), $O\in\mathfrak{I}\implies O':=O\cap Y\in \mathfrak{I}'.$

It is not correct.
You can write your first implication in the form
$$\forall O'\in\mathfrak{I}' \exists\ O\in\mathfrak{I} : O' = O\cap Y \tag {1}$$
But this does not mean that all intersections $O\cap Y$ with $O\in\mathfrak{I}$ belong to $\mathfrak{I}'$. For example, if $\mathfrak{I}'$ is the trivial topology on $Y$, then $(1)$ is satisfied for any $\mathfrak{I}$.
You can write your second implication in the form
$$\forall O\in\mathfrak{I} : O' = O\cap Y \in \mathfrak{I}' \tag{2}$$
But this does not mean that all elements of $\mathfrak{I}'$ have the form $O\cap Y$ with $O\in\mathfrak{I}$ . For example, if $\mathfrak{I}'$ is the discrete topology on $Y$, then $(2)$ is satisfied for any $\mathfrak{I}$.
Therefore you need both $(1)$ and $(2)$. This is the meaning of

the open subsets of $Y$ are precisely the subsets $O'$ of the form $ O' = O\cap Y$.

Concerning Lemma 6.4 let us consider a metric space $(X,d)$ and a subset $Y \subset X$. Denote by $(X,\mathfrak{I}) = (X, \mathfrak{I}_{metric})$ the topological space associated with $(X,d)$ and by $d'$ the restriction of $d$ to $Y$. Then $(Y,d')$ is the metric subspace of $(X,d)$ with underlying set $Y$. We can now consider two topological spaces with underlying set $Y$:

The subspace $(Y,\mathfrak{I}'_{subspace})$ of $(X,\mathfrak{I}_{metric})$.
The topological space $(Y,\mathfrak{I}'_{metric})$ associated with $(Y,d')$.

Lemma 6.4 says that $(Y,\mathfrak{I}'_{metric})$ is a subspace of $(X,\mathfrak{I}_{metric})$. Since the subspace topology on $Y$ is in uniquely determined by $\mathfrak{I}$, this means $(Y,\mathfrak{I}'_{metric}) = (Y,\mathfrak{I}'_{subspace})$.
Your Lemma 6.4a says that  $(Y,\mathfrak{I}'_{subspace})$ is the topological space  associated with $(Y,d')$. Since the topology associated to a metric is uniquely determined by the metric, this means again $(Y,\mathfrak{I}'_{subspace}) = (Y,\mathfrak{I}'_{metric})$.
Therefore both formulations of the Lemma are equivalent. If you accept that Mendelson proved Lemma 6.4a, then you see that he also proved Lemma 6.4.
